# Firebase onChildChanged() get called 3 times though I changed a value twice

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

It's not every time but sometimes (I feel like it's 10%) onChildChanged() method get called 3 times though I actually changed twice.

Here are Logs.

This is a log when I change a value twice.  (true → false → true, ※the original value was true)

```
05-20 12:39:14.948 3960-3960/com.yoji0806.wastekiller1 I/childChanged: check: false, tablet: 1
05-20 12:39:14.948 3960-3960/com.yoji0806.wastekiller1 I/childChanged: check: true, tablet: 1
05-20 12:39:16.276 3960-3960/com.yoji0806.wastekiller1 I/printReceipt: table: TN 18
```

And this is a log when onChildChanged() get called 3 times though I changed a value only twice.　(true → false → true, ※the original value was true)

```
05-20 12:39:40.818 3960-3960/com.yoji0806.wastekiller1 I/childChanged: check: true, tablet: 1
05-20 12:39:40.820 3960-3960/com.yoji0806.wastekiller1 I/childChanged: check: false, tablet: 1
05-20 12:39:40.822 3960-3960/com.yoji0806.wastekiller1 I/childChanged: check: true, tablet: 1
05-20 12:39:41.670 3960-3960/com.yoji0806.wastekiller1 I/printReceipt:table: TN 18      
05-20 12:39:46.376 3960-3960/com.yoji0806.wastekiller1 I/printReceiot:table: TN 18
```

I don't know what happened at the first line Log above. Although the original value was true, it captured a change from "true" to "true".

This is my code.

```
private val listener = object : ChildEventListener{
    override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {}
    override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {}
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}

    override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?){

        val check: Boolean = p0.child("check").value.toString().toBoolean()
        val tablet = p0.child("tablet").value.toString()


        Log.i("childAdded:" , "check: $check, tablet: $tablet")


        if (check){
            val tableNum = p0.key.toString()
            readData(tableNum, tablet)
        }
    }

    override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {

        val check: Boolean = p0.child("check").value.toString().toBoolean()
        val tablet = p0.child("tablet").value.toString()


        Log.i("childChanged:", "check: $check, tablet: $tablet")


        if (check){
            val tableNum = p0.key.toString()
            readData(tableNum, tablet)
        }
    }
}

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive)

    val mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

    mDatabase.getReference("Checker").addChildEventListener(listener)
  }
```

**Add**

・Before I took these two Logs above, I had already attached the listener and as log timestamp shows I took the second Log soon after I took the first Log. Between two actions(took 2 Logs) I didn't any action.

・I use two types of tablets. One is for writing into DB, the other one is for listening changes on DB. The problem is occurring in a type-2 tablet.

Answer (score 0):

it is trivial.
any state change listener will be called

> the number of times change made + FIRST TIME THE LISTENER WAS ATTACHED

.

Which means, your child changed listener was  called the first time you when you attached it.
Then it was called the second time u made a change.
Then the third time u made the last change.
Total = 3.

Comment: Before I took two Logs above, I had already attached the listener. And as these log times show, I got the second log soon after I got the first log.

Comment: the first instance is called the moment you attach the listener

Comment: I edited my code. I think the moment I attach the listener is when onCreate() called, so it has nothing to do the first line in the second log, am I right? Plus, this happens only sometimes(8~10%).

Comment: you get data inside listener both when u r writiing and reading

Comment: I built two application with one Firebase DB and this one is only for reading, not writing at all.